# Cant Call setBlockedURLs WebView2

Tags: vb.net, webview2

I try to control the `setBlockedURLs` protocol, but it did not work and the program does not give me any error, I tried to replace “ with ' but then it gives me an error
where did I go wrong?

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await Web.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Network.setBlockedURLs", "{""urls"":[""https://www.google.com/""]}")
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, if i change the way it is written it will show "System.ArgumentException" error, but if i leave it as it is, it won't show any error but it doesn't add anything that's weird

Comment: @PoulBak The verbatim doesn't help much in VB.Net. Anyway, this is an experimental feature, no guarantees it's implemented in whatever version of WebView2 the OP is using.

Comment: @PoulBak According to what it says it accepts json string , yes Jimi I didn't notice it's experimental, I tried it also in c but it didn't work either, it seems to be a problem with WebView2

Comment: Yes, that parameter is a JSON object. When no parameters are required, you specify an empty JSON object: `"{}"`. -- I gave it a go, most recent WebView2 version available, also setting `var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions("--force-devtools-available", null, null, false); var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, options); await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);`. The call to `CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Network.setBlockedURLs", urls)` is accepted (throws if the JSON is not valid) but the Urls specified are not blocked.